# Cannot access encrypted root partition after moving it

Tags: linux, grub2, disk-encryption

I had a Windows laptop with an additional Manjaro installed, on `/dev/sda6` (somewhere  wedged between the Windows 10 main partition and the recovery partiton).
The Manjaro partition is using ext4, with full encryption.

I decided to get rid of Windows, and deleted the corresponding partitions, leaving only `/dev/sda1` (UEFI or something) and `/dev/sda6`.
Extending `/dev/sda6` was easily achieved from within Manjaro, using the KDE partitioner, but it didn't want to move its own root partition, of course.
I tested that everything still worked fine after extending the partition to use the space freed up by the Windows recovery.

I then moved the partition to the front of the free space, using a live image of Manjaro (the one from wich it had originally been installed). This also worked without issues (that I noticed), but now I cannot boot it anymore.

Grub reports (I shortened the UUID of the partition in question):

```
error: no such cryptodisk found
error: disk `cryptouuid/30c...a1` not found
Entering rescue mode...
```

I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605971/grub-cannot-find-encrypted-boot-partition) question which looks similar but did not really apply to my case since I know that the partition and grub *can* work with each other.

I also found [this](https://itectec.com/superuser/grub-bootloader-with-root-luks-encryption-only-grub-shell/) article, which helped me try a few things:

- the partition is found at `(hd0,gpt6)`
- `ls (hd0,6)` yields `Filesystem is unknown`
- `insmod cryptodisk`, `insmod luks` both work
- `insmod ext4` fails, with `'cryptouuid/30c...a1' not found`
  Any command referencing `(hd0,6)` produces the same error message.

I'm not at all used to the grub console, so I'm not really sure what I could to to help grub out there.

Going back to the live image of Manjaro, the partition editor finds the partition, but shows the type as "unknown" -- I'm unfortunately not sure if it correclty identified it as ext4 before the move or if encrypted partitions are always shown this way. There is no option to mount the partition.

So, the question is: Can I still get grub to boot from this partition, nd if yes, how?
Or has it been damaged during the move, and it's over? (and if yes, what did I do wrong? I found others moving their root partitions this way)
There is a backup of the partition, although there's also about one day's worth of work which has not been backed up (I really should have...) , so I'd very much prefer getting all the contents back in good order...

I have super Grub Disk here (which finds the root partition and the .efi corresponding efi file, and Clonezilla (which I used for the backup), but no good strategy for how to proceed.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm encountering a similar problem now after a windows update

Comment: I did not really solve it. I restored all the old partitions from the clonezilla image I had taken, then made a copy of the Linux /home dir, and installed Manjaro from scratch, chosing to remove all other OSes on the drive and replace them with one new, encrypted, partition for Manjaro. This kept the UEFI partition intact, and I could boot just fine after that (and copy back all the deleted user data). I have a suspicion that an encrypted partition cannot be moved, but have found no reliable information on this.